# Match a word that's 3 or more letter words that's not a certain word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match any 3 or more letter words after "do you" that's not the word "lie", but when I tried it when less than 3 words, it doesn't work properly. How do I fix this?

```
$text = "do you a";
if (preg_match("~(do you) (?!lie){3,}~", $text)) { echo "it matched!"; }
```

It echoed "it matched" when it's not suppose to match.

Comment: Directly after `do you` or anytime after? Does it have to be regex? It seems simpler to do without regex

Comment: You wrote "I need to match any 3 or more". Why "when I tried it when less than 3 words, it doesn't work properly" it should work for less than 3 than?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is not correct. You can't apply quantifier to a negative look ahead pattern and must write your pattern like this,

```
(do you) (?!lie\b)[a-zA-Z]{3,}
```

Also, you should use word boundary `\b` to make it not match just `lie` but let it match other words like `lied`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6y8hSk/1)**

**[PHP Code demo](https://rextester.com/ELE28918)**

```
$text = "do you a";
if (preg_match("~(do you) (?!lie\b)[a-zA-Z]{3,}~", $text)) { echo "it matched! ".$text; }
$text = "do you lie";
if (preg_match("~(do you) (?!lie\b)[a-zA-Z]{3,}~", $text)) { echo "it matched! ".$text; }
$text = "do you lied";
if (preg_match("~(do you) (?!lie\b)[a-zA-Z]{3,}~", $text)) { echo "it matched! ".$text; }
```

Prints only this,

```
it matched! do you lied
```

Comment: Good catch on the `do you lied` test case.

Answer (score 1):

A non regex version is to explode the sentence on `do you` and on space and see what word is after `do you` then make sure it's a string, more than three characters and is not "lie".

```
$text = "John do you know a lie";
$after = explode(" ", explode("do you ", $text)[1])[0];
echo $after;

if(strlen($after) >=3 && is_string($after) && strtolower($after) != "lie"){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tJ754

If the string don't always contain `do you` then you need to check the array after the first explode if it has a second item.
Else it will return a notice, undefined [1].

```
$text = "John do know a lie";
$temp = explode("do you ", $text);

if(isset($temp[1])){
    $after = explode(" ", $temp[1])[0];
}else{
    $after = null;
}
echo $after;

if(strlen($after) >=3 && is_string($after) && strtolower($after) != "lie"){
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```